# jQuery: how to pass a variable into a selector

Tags: jquery

I looked on here, but couldn't find anything that applies to what I am trying to do.  Here is my AJAX call, which is a click event for delete_item:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/cms/delete'); ?>',
    data: 'article_id=' + article_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false, 
    success: function(data) {
         $('li').remove($(this).id);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error occurred: ' + status); 
    }
});
```

It's the line with the remove call in it that's not working.  $(this).id correctly refers to the id of the li I am trying to remove.  I think my problem is my use of the remove call.  I think I have something wrong in the syntax, but I can't tell what.  I followed the API but they weren't as specific as this.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

Oh, my DOM looks like this:

```
<li id="26"><a class="delete_item" ...></a><li>
```

Comment: Well, first off `$(this).id` does not look right, since I don't think `$()` has an `.id` property. `this.id` should should work, or `$(this).prop('id')`. The first should be "faster" since it doesn't require jQuery's overhead to get that property of the element.

Comment: FYI, ids should begin with a letter. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Second, `this` inside the callback does not refer to the DOM element.

Comment: From the documentation: *"The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context` option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified, `this` is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
$(this).remove();
```

You may want to cache a reference to the current 'this', especially if you're running the script asyncronously:

```
var pEl = $(this);
$.ajax({...snip...
    success:function(data){
        pEl.remove();
    }
```

Comment: I can't do that because this is the a tag the link is on.  See my edit above.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense.  The ID you're attempting to remove is the ID of the element anyway.

Comment: There is no need to pass `pEl` to jQuery again. `pEl.remov()` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the link controls whenever this ajax call is running, so $(this) object is referring to the < a > not the < li > element. And you can not use it directly inside the success event. So here is what you may do:

1. at "channel_partners/cms/delete" you may return the deleted item's id back on successful deletion
2. then you can use to delete the li element like this:

   ```
   $("li[id=" + data + "]").remove();
   ```

By using like this, you may get unsuccessful deletion results from the server too with returning data like "ERROR" from the server.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("li").attr("id",$(this).id).remove()
```

Comment: Even if `$(this).id` was returning the ID, this would set the id of all `li` elements to that value and then remove all `li` elements.

Comment: Firebug says that's not a function.

Comment: Then how do I remove just the one I want.

Comment: @shummel7845: John already provided an answer. If that does not work for you, you have to provide more information. Maybe the event handler is not bound to the `li` element and therefore `this` does not reference the `li` element... but only you know.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks, Felix and John.